# Problemas al mover entre columnas un registro mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas, quien me podría ayudar con esto.

Es un sistema para llevar el control de agenda, por días.
Los que pasa es que cuando ingreso un registro el primero lo cuadra bien. de 10:00 a 14:00, pero cuando ingreso otro me vuelve a sumar los  y los corre al final, el registro 12333 debería empezar en 15:00 hasta 16:00 y el 30125 de 20:00 hasta las 22:00..

como podría hacer para que  los registros correspondan a cada hora...

```
$query1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT *  FROM calendar WHERE id = 's5' and id_year = '2018' and id_mes = '9'");

while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
{

$p = 0;

for($k= 3;$k<=9;$k++){

if($resultado[$k] != null)
{$mescompleto = $resultado[$k].'/'.$resultado['id_mes'].'/'.$year;}
if($resultado[$k]<10)
{$mescompleto = '0'.$resultado[$k].'/'.$resultado['id_mes'].'/'.$year;}
if($resultado['id_mes']<10){$mescompleto = $resultado[$k].'/'.'0'.$resultado['id_mes'].'/'.$year;}  
if($resultado[$k]<10 && $resultado['id_mes']<10){$mescompleto = '0'.$resultado[$k].'/'.'0'.$resultado['id_mes'].'/'.$year;}
if($resultado[$k] == null)
{$mescompleto = "";}


?>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan="5" scope="row" ><p class="rot inline-block"><?php echo $dias[$p]; ?><br> <?php echo $mescompleto; ?></p></td>
    </tr>


<tr>
<td colspan="3"><p class="th">Lavado</p></td>

<?php

$query2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tiempo where fecha = '$mescompleto' and id_maq = '1' order by hora_ini ");
   $num = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
$xa=0;  
$h=1;   

while($tiempos = mysqli_fetch_array($query2))
{


$v = $hi = trim(substr($tiempos['hora_ini'],0,-3));
$b = $hf = trim(substr($tiempos['hora_fin'],0,-3));
$tp = $tiempos['fecha'];
$nv = $tiempos['id_nv'];
$com = $tiempos['comentario'];
$idm = $tiempos['id_maq'];

$fecha1 = new DateTime($tiempos['hora_ini']);//fecha inicial
$fecha2 = new DateTime($tiempos['hora_fin']);//fecha de cierre

$intervalo = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);

$intervalo->format('%H h %i m');//00 años 0 meses 0 días 08 horas 0 minutos 0 segundos

if($mescompleto == $tp && $idm == 1)
{

 //Aqui agrega los <td>


    for($i=1;$i<$x;$i++)
    {

    echo '<td cospan=""></td>';

    }

    $s = $intervalo->format('%H') + 1;


?>
<td colspan = "<?php echo $s ?>" >

  <div class="progress-bar" style="width:100%;height:20px" onMouseover="fixedtooltip('<?php echo $com?>', this, event, '120px')" onMouseout="delayhidetip()" >
   <?php echo $nv; ?>
  </div>

</td>

<?php

}
$xa = $x + 1;
$h++;
}
?>  
</tr>
```

Comment: Va a ser necesario que especifiques el formato de datos, y de preferencia des información de como construyes ese "resultado erróneo" que muestras, como bien puede ser la consulta SQL, y así encontrar el problema.

Comment: La parte de la consulta.

Comment: Dire que no entiendo del todo tu codigo, pero por lo que dices si el problema esta en las columnas "De mas" que te genera el for, el problema esta en los limites del for. No veo en que parte del código se calcula la `$x` utilizada como limite superior del for. Asi que lo que aconsejo es utilizar un `While ($i<$x)`, con el `$i++;` interno, y no inicializado al inicio del while, por lo tanto se conserva, ademas deberias sumar al `$i` cada columna (con horario ocupado) que utilices, así `$i` reprecentará "hasta que columna" has trabajado, cuando uses una nueva linea, deberás volverla 1. (`$i=1;`)